# Is email from do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email legit?

Tags: support, email, security

I've just received an email from `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email` titled *Announcing the Stack Overflow Developer Story*.

Is this a legit email? If so, how come you use this domain while other emails (e.g. job matches) come from `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com`?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

**Yes** it is legit. We use it to protect `stackoverflow.com` user cookies from third parties. The links in the email are all rewritten to a `stackoverflow.email` subdomain, CNAMEd to a third party service we use for sending emails, and tracking email stats (spam reports, bounces, deliveries, views, clicks).

If we'd add a CNAME to a third party under the `stackoverflow.com` domain, they'd receive all our users cookies, which some sites are OK with, but we aren't.

Another possible mitigation of this would be to set the [secure flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) on our user's cookies, and leave the third-party links as HTTP. We're not able to do that yet, since official HTTPS support is still 6-8 weeks from shipping. Ultimately, we want *both* links to be HTTPS, anyway.

#### TL;DR

You can verify this by visiting [Stack Overflow via HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com), and looking at the certificate - it's the same one we use on [stackoverflow.email](https://stackoverflow.email).

Comment: surely the from address doesn't need to match the tracking domain?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I guess it helps against spam filters though

Comment: exactly, the email's from address' domain gets checked via SPF / DKIM / DMARC, servers and clients can consider links to it verified

Comment: Then this should be announced beforehand through official channels, because I thought it's phishing too. Especially when my mail client (Thunderbird) is putting big red warnings all over it that it is a possible scam :P All the links are obfuscated and looking at the source shows thtat the message bounced through several wanky third-party servers. I think that the only thing you forgot to put in there is some penile enlargement ads :q

Comment: @SasQ what would you consider "beforehand" enough? We've been sending most emails through that domain for more than 2 years now.

OTOH a big red warning in an email client is not desired behavior, so we'd really appreciate a separate question tagged [tag:bug] or [tag:support], with the email details (at least the subject), your email provider / client details, exact warning message you see, chain of redirects for links that you consider malicious etc.

Comment: By "beforehand" I meant sending a message from your official domain FIRST, informing the users that the new domain will be used and it is legitimate, so that they could add it to their whitelists instead of being surprised by fishy domains and dodgy-looking obfuscated URLs in messages coming from them. I haven't received any such notification, the messages just started coming from a different domain one day (October 13th, 2018, to be exact). First I just ignored them as phishing attempts, until they become too specific – then I started suspecting a data leak. Congratulations :q

Comment: @Mosa stackoverflow.email is not a subdomain of stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne the emails are *sent* from a subdomain of `stackoverflow.email`. No mention of `stackoverflow.com` being a subdomain...

Comment: @DeanWard I think Jonathan's point was that if .email is a TLD, then `stackoverflow.email` and `stackoverflow.com` are two separate top level domain sites. But to clarify for others, it sounds like you're saying some subdomain of the TLD `stackoverflow.email`, e.g. `research.stackoverflow.email`, in order to fully protect the .com domain from 3rd parties.

Comment: The SO site GUI needs to clearly say what sites a SO email might come from in the places where people can request interaction with SO that can result in an email from other than stackoverflow.com. It wasn't easy to find this post or any other info re whether the survey email i just got from stackoverflow.email is legitimate, including googling with 'site:meta.stackoverflow.com "stackoverflow.email" from stack overflow'.