# Is "newsletter@stackoverflow.net" a legitimate email from SO?

Tags: support, email

Recently, I received an email from this address about signing up to a Stack Overflow newsletter. Has anyone else received an email like this and is it a  legitimate email?

Comment: stackoverflow.net is *not* part of the network. Looks like a phishing attempt to me by that reason alone.

Comment: Related: [Is email from do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email legit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338332)

Comment: Please forward a full copy of the email (including headers) to team@stackoverflow.com so we can look into this.

Comment: Note the email address can be faked. Even if it was stackoverflow.com, it wouldn't necessarily mean it's legitimate.

Comment: @Oriol that's why the headers matter :)

Comment: That email address looks pretty phishy to me...

Comment: Perhaps a good time to have `stackoverflow.net` suspended for violating copyright & generally using the domain for malicious use?

Answer (score 76):

Doesn't look like it

```
Domain Name: STACKOVERFLOW.NET
Registrant Name: ANDREA STEIN
Registrant Organization: -
Registrant Street: 50 BRIDGE STREET, #412
Registrant City: BROOKLYN
Registrant State/Province: NY
Registrant Postal Code: 11201
Registrant Country: US
```

Vs

```
Domain Name: STACKOVERFLOW.COM
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: Sysadmin Team
Registrant Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Registrant Street: 110 William St , Floor 28
Registrant City: New York
Registrant State/Province: NY
Registrant Postal Code: 10038
Registrant Country: US
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.net redirects to http://caroftomorrow.com/

Comment: so should really buy stackoverflow.net and redirect to stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JonH that's easier said than done

Comment: @zurfyx - I know but it is worth attempting - yes it might cost some money - but in my opinion it may be well worth it.

Comment: Maybe Professor Stein's daughter?

Comment: @JonH There's actually a [process you can go through with ICANN](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/help/dndr/udrp-en) to seize domains being used to violate Trademarks (which I assume SO is trademarked)

Comment: @hackerman what makes you think it's a she? It might be an evil italian spy...

Comment: Amazing how the internet can find so much about an individual.  Ya'll are a bunch of no good hackers! ;-)

Comment: Step 1: buy 1-off TLD of similar popular site. Step 2: leave who-is info available so popular site can contact. Step 3: ... Step 4: PROFIT!!!

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrea-stein-davis-4491494  This has got to be a legal issue at this point.  This person is claiming ownership of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @CodyGray JonH's comment appears to be in jest, so I assume you're responding to someone who later deleted their comments?

Comment: @KyleStrand A lot of comments have been deleted, probably by mods. We'll just leave it at that

Comment: @DavidL Seems suspect, but there is the possibility that this person has a company who, possibly intentionally, decided to register a company called StackOverflow (and Bootstrap, very unlikely coincidence) in a territory outside the US or the UK, making this almost impossible to litigate. Lack of jurisdiction, and all that.

Comment: @KarlBuys interesting point...and possibly true.  I suppose time will tell.

Comment: Deleted my own comments. Although they'd been highly upvoted, they didn't make sense in the thread of conversation any more. I don't really care for the way that comments are handled, but the community disagrees with me here.

Comment: Just to add my 2c to this - it looks like stackoverflow.net is a legitimate domain for a company (consultancy, looking at linkedin) that no longer exists (and hasn't for around 6 years). Probably the address in the phishing mail was just spoofed and not affiliated with stackoverflow.net.