# Can SO stop sending mails from @stackoverflow.email now that it is on SSL?

Tags: discussion, support, email

Stack Overflow is sending out some E-Mails using the `@stackoverflow.email` domain. M0sa explains why [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338334/187606), but there are several downsides to this practice:

- They confuse people as to the authenticity of incoming E-Mails. Already visible in a number of [Meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=stackoverflow.email). There are real people out there [impersonating Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364479). Also there's an increased risk of some bozo registering `stackoverflow.network` or whatever and sending E-Mails from it
- In my experience, sender addresses with newfangled TLDs are a spam red flag. I get loads of spam and literally ALL the messages I get from `.website`, `.email`, `.company`, `.network` and such are garbage, to the point that I've considered adding a filter rejecting them all with a friendly explanation. I'm sure I'm not the only one
- People with very strict spam regimes might have `@stackoverflow.com` whitelisted but not `@stackoverflow.email`

Now that Stack Overflow is completely on SSL, which M0sa lists as one reason why the .email domain is used - is this worth revisiting?

Comment: Facebook is also doing this work. I asked a question about it in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113542/is-there-any-advantage-using-separate-domain-for-mails too.

Comment: I'm past considering filtering new TLDs. I'm *there*.

Comment: There's also [stackoverflow.net](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342236/is-newsletterstackoverflow-net-a-legitimate-email-from-so) (which is apparently now owned by a web development software firm)

Comment: There is still a problem with the 3th party software required for tracking the emails, now they are free to change it, but if emails come (and have tracking links to) stackoverflow.com, you  need to security screen them

Comment: If they pick _one_ official one to use for correspondence does it matter which one it is? It does seem odd to get it from multiple domains unless this is some sort of AB test

Comment: Well I guess people are going to miss emails from me if you all block the new fangled TLDs! Another reason we need to find an alternative to email really, it's an awful communication mechanism.

Comment: @DavidG did you get my smoke signals?

Comment: @David LOL! Yours is the first justifiable use of a newfangled TLD I've ever seen. If I ever create a filter like that, I'll make sure to whitelist `.glass`.

Comment: @rene I thought something was on fire...

Comment: @Pekka웃 The moment I saw it was available, I bought it. Slightly more expensive than a standard TLD but worth every penny. Worth it just for the confused look on people's faces when I read out my email address.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

We cannot use the same domain because we send email through some third parties for scale (like SendGrid and Iterable). Independent from the HTTPS/SSL issue, for any requests made through them (even redirects), **they would get your cookies** if we were using the same second level domain.

The split is very intentional, so that this cookie theft cannot happen and remains under our control.

If we relied on them being HTTP-only forever (let's also try to agree this is a bad idea from the start), these third party image and click relays would be able to, at will, enable SSL and start viewing the cookies (even via HSTS or via preload) without our consent or knowledge. Since I'm also working on getting us added to the HSTS preload list for Chrome (which feeds downstream to all major browsers), this path would also break completely very soon.

HTTPS was the initial reason (HSTS), but cookies is an equal concern today we cannot work around (at least within the current constraints of web browsers). That's the primary reason for our `.email` and `.blog` domains.

Comment: If you don't understand what Nick is saying, [here's a handy illustration](https://images.food52.com/IWhtdkey_7ExuzrobeVsj9nMqtI=/fit-in/800x0/d0643f40-d7d7-415b-84f8-2fd4dc093c8e--2015-1209_cookie-monster-gif_2_layers.gif)

Comment: @Machavity ugh you got me

Comment: Well, I don't want any third-party website to either steal my cookies or track me, so I won't click on those wanky links in your wanky new e-mail anyway. Way to shot in your foot...

Comment: @SasQ For what it's worth, we don't care what *a* user clicks, but we have to care in aggregate as we want to improve what newsletters people like, increase usability overall, etc. and we have to measure to see if we're doing better or worse. This is fairly normal for anyone at scale. Note though that your behavior isn't reflected in the vast majority of users, so I don't agree with a "shooting ourselves in the foot" assessment. We know we can't please everyone - it's just not possible when talking about many millions of users.

Comment: I might have believed that if the usability were actually improving. (cough!%logout button, for one%cough!). As for the brilliant idea with fishy TLDs for official mailings, you've got my feedback above.

Comment: @SasQ Noted - I just don't think we'll agree here. It's part of my job to maintain the security of our users and network and this was a necessary step. We're working on a lot of usability in many places (for example, load this page in desktop mode on mobile). There's a lot to do, but we are working on it. As with all things, resources are finite.

Comment: Can someone share some more info (or articles/docs) about how third-party can access the cookies. It went over my head.