# Registration email https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email

Tags: bug, registration

Inquiry: Why does the Registration email  direct to https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email

Answer (score 3):

The company that runs the site Stack Overflow, runs also 170+ other sites where some have dedicated domains as well. To reduce overhead, complexity, cost and make it easier to maintain Stack Exchange bought one domain, stackoverflow.email, to act as their email domain, for all sites, including Stack Overflow.

[Here is comment from Nick Craver (Architecture Lead)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301957/why-are-stack-exchange-profile-deletion-email-notifications-sent-from-stack-over#comment982015_301957)

> It's not about buying 2 domains, we'd have to buy many more than that, Ask Ubuntu, Math Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, Stack Apps, and Stack Exchange .email domains. Then we'd need certificates for all of them. And we'd need IPs or aliases for them. And DMARC support. And reputation monitoring. And we'd have to build into the entire system what to send from where. These added up are significantly more than "just buying another domain
> One more note: bear in mind when people want to whitelist our email address so they always get it, we'd be asking users to whitelist 7 domains (so far), not just one. That's cost put on users, not us. That is something we very actively try to avoid.

So it is a matter of convenience for the company and for users that have accounts on more then just Stack Overflow.

The domain is legit and under control of Stack Overflow.

There is also a security concern if the domain is the same as stackoverflow.com, as explained here: [Can SO stop sending mails from @stackoverflow.email now that it is on SSL?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364903/can-so-stop-sending-mails-from-stackoverflow-email-now-that-it-is-on-ssl)

So this not a bug, it is [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)