# Is my "Comment Evaluator 5000™" campaign email legit?

Tags: discussion, email, security, comment-evaluator-5000

How do I know a "Comment Evaluator 5000™" email I received is legit?

I mean, I got an email from some weird address (comment-classification@stackoverflow.email), note "stackoverflow.email", not "stackoverflow.com". So I do I know if it comes from here.

Silly me I have not noticed it immediately, so I clicked a "rate some comments!" button. Then I get redirected to a even weirder address: https://royal-millennium.glitch.me/

what...? glitch.me...?! That I noticed :-)

Then... I don't know, because I don't see any difference between that mailing and some fraud, I sure have not logged in through that page.

Is someone impersonating stackoverflow.com?
Or is this a very very bad message? I guess so...

Should I ask this at security.stackexchange.com (I don't have an account there, but I would appreciate if someone asked this, because other institutions, including my *bank*!, do the same)

In short, how do we distinguish this from phishing / malware / social hacking / ...?

EDIT:
The initial question is answered in the other question (stackoverflow.email is legit). Thank you for pointing to that, I looked mostly for "Comment Evaluator" so I have not found that one.

Yet the main point was in my last sentence: Howe do we distiguish this from phishig, and so on? Note that there is also a [question about a @stackoverflow.net email](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342236/is-newsletterstackoverflow-net-a-legitimate-email-from-so) whis is NOT a legit address. So, how do we know? And is this good security practice? I note that stackoverflow (as many other companies, I know) make their users used to replying to strange addresses linking to weird site addresses. Aren't they teaching users to be careless?

Again, if best to as elsewhere, please say so.

NOTE: Template messages are HORRIBLE. I have no idea how to comment, who to address my message, no idea if anyone will read this... not a friendly system at all.

Comment: Glitch.me is a domain under control of SE, kind of.

Comment: glitch.me redirects to glitch.com, a domain owned by Fog Creek Software. Which is Joel Spolsky's first company. It is legit.  It is worth taking a peek at glitch.com btw, the site goal does seem to make all of the [welcoming] misery seem like a sales-pitch.