# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when visiting https://stackoverflowbusiness.com/

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-business

When visiting https://stackoverflowbusiness.com/ I get a NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. This doesn't happen for https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/.

The certificate in question is for `*.stackexchange.com` instead of `stackoverflowbusiness.com`.

I'm on
Windows 7
Vivaldi 2.6.1566.44 (Stable channel) (32-Bit)

as well as on

Chrome 75.0.3770.142

Comment: Totally unrelated, but why isn't that on the SO or SE domain? `business.stackoverflow.com` or something like that? My first instinct would be to disregard a domain like that as spam / fake.

Comment: Is this a real domain from SO? Or just fake?

Comment: Meta.SO seems to use other certificate. 4F:21:65:05:D6:3E:A2:11:5D:54:11:DE:30:3B:FF:51:CE:64:2C:A1:9F:09:91:C2:58:AB:17:E8:34:04:25:D8 vs 8B:EF:BC:1D:17:75:4A:95:B5:AE:10:76:5E:66:31:2C:21:05:21:90:56:74:AC:00:F7:61:0F:3A:AF:09:D2:30. That's not damning, since they could live in different haproxy servers. Also, Let's Encrypt verifies each domain under alt names, and those are SE domains. The bug here is that that certificate isn't using stackoverflowbusiness.com as alt name.

Comment: No, it's real, @BDL.

Comment: @Cerbrus now that you mention it, maybe `teams.stackoverflow.com` and `jobs.stackoverflow.com` might have been better too and would've solved the issue with polluting the original SO site.

Comment: @Cerbrus Can you provide some documentary evidence for this? As you know, best practice is not to just trust someone saying this when there's a dud cert :)

Comment: @Braiam The website in question does not use that SO cert. www.stackoverflowbusiness.com uses a CloudFare cert - the bug is that _that_ cert does not have stackoverflowbusiness.com as an alt name. Pretty basic server admin fail!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Actually, when I went to stackoverflowbusiness.com I got the *.stackexchange.com cert

Comment: @JamesKPolk Sorry yes meant to say the bug is that the wrong cert is being served _and_ it doesn't have the alt name on it. But there is no mention of stackoverflowbusiness.com in any form in the base SO cert being served by the domain in question

Comment: Also btw that site says "© 2017 Stack Overflow" on it...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: for the fact it's a SE domain? `Registrant Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.` ([source](http://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflowbusiness.com))

Comment: @Cerbrus Is that information not trivially forgable? I'd like a staffer to tell us for sure whether this is a genuine site. (N.B. This discussion for me is _mostly_ out of principle; in this case it does seem highly unlikely to be a forgery!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, and also trivially verifiable, but I'm guessing you expected that whois info with my _"No, it's real,"_. You doubt the whois information?

Comment: @Cerbrus Whether I doubt it or not is not really the point; the point is whether the evidence you have provided as to the authentic owner of the website is actually evidence, or just another potential forgery. I don't know what sort of verifications registrars typically perform when someone submits their company name for WHOIS purposes. Perhaps there is some. Perhaps there is not.

Comment: Well, that's not weird at all, now I'm resolving to a cloudflare ip.

Comment: My guess is someone forgot to redirect the non-www variant in DNS.

Comment: The domain seems legit, under https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact in **Stack Overflow Business Solutions**, the link *www.stackoverflowbusiness.com* is used 3 times. On the full page 11 times. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Also in footer, **Products > Talent** and **Products > Advertising**

Comment: @André Excellent, thank you

Comment: @DavidG Nope, it's a page that redirects to www.stackoverflowbusiness.com (if you ignore the bad cert)

Comment: The domain is a legit Stack Overflow domain. We're looking into the cert issue now.

Comment: For those that asked, this is intentionally not on the stackoverflow.com domain, as it's hosted by a thirdparty CMS and we didn't want to leak security cookies, etc, across the domains.  It's the same reasons we have stackoverflow.email and similar domains. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338334/682840

Answer (score 1):

Since the apex of the domain is just a redirect to the `www` name, I think we missed ever setting up working TLS for the redirect and just depended on all the HTTPS links being pointed directly to `www`, which isn't great.

We've rolled out a new cert for the redirect listener covering this domain, should be good to go!

For those curious about the thumbprint mismatch between that cert and the cert you're seeing here, the reason for this is that we use different-but-almost-identical certificates for our internal infrastructure and that of our CDN, Fastly, to limit the potential impact of a compromise of a private key from either location; this redirect is served directly from our load balancers due to the low request volume.