# Long words in a question/post don't cooperate well with the Community Bulletin

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design, community-bulletin

[One of the current Hot Meta Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387522/3151675) has a title with a long word, which causes an overflow:

[image: screenshot of the question title which causes the bug]

Interestingly enough, that title appears with a word break in the Linked section of this very question:

[image: screenshot of the same question in the Linked section]

macOS 10.15 beta 4, Chrome 75

Comment: That error causes the site to break in ways they never imagined!

Comment: [also reported at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331252/165773)

Comment: ah I would love to see this one Hot : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375101/8620333 .. we will have a lot of fun

Comment: `word-break: break-word;` would fix this

Comment: Looks like they [fixed this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator)